# how to get JSON data from server to build a graph using chart.js

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on ordering and displaying users with most activities . received from server, i want to display all data as a graph using charts.js. The server data i.e. "clara , 4 activities" , "joe, 7 activities". etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var data = [4, 7];
var labels =  ["clara", "joe"]    

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Activities',
            data: data,
        }]
    },
});
```

Using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Your url",
    success: function (result) {
        var data = [];
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: result.labels,
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Activities',
                        data: result.data,
                    }]
            },
        });
    }
});
```

You have to pass a dataset like this from backend,

```
{
    "chartData": {
        "labels": [
            "clara",
            "joe"
        ],
        "data": [
            4,
            7
        ]
    }
}
```

Also here is a nice [Tutorial](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/exploring-chart-js-e3ba70b07aa4) about this.

Comment: thank you but i try what you send abd it works , but now the "var data = [4,7] " : is what i want dynamically from server

Comment: For that you may have to call `$.ajax` and call `var myChart = new Chart(ctx,.. ` inside success method.

Comment: send me a screen please, one of how you transform data in JSON and another to show me how you call it in the chart

Comment: The tutorial I linked have a complete description on how to do that. Think it will more descriptive and helpful

Comment: Sorry I was busy earlier. Added a solution. Please add desired url instead of Your url